# RBAC в Yii.Помогите разобраться

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Всем доброго времени суток.
Только недавно начал изучать Yii2, и понадобилось выучить RBAC.
Но сколько бы документаций и мануалов я не читал.все равно не пойму.
Может кто,скинуть либо на понятную статью как сделать,либо помочь
**Суть**
На данный момент у меня есть таблица с пользователями(Логин,пароль,роль)
Нужно сделать запрет на посещение страницы определенной роли,нашел простецкую статью https://vk.cc/6F7iKN . 
И тут столкнулся с проблемой в пункте:

> > Теперь в БД нужно создать необходимые таблицы, в которых будут храниться разрешения, роли, назначения… Для этого можно выполнить
> >     миграции, которые лежат в «коробке». В консоли выполняем: php yii
> >     migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations
>
> Это создаст 4 таблицы в БД:
>
> auth_item - эта таблица хранит роли и разрешения.
>
> auth_item_child - здесь задаются наследования.
>
> auth_assignment - тут пользователям назначаются позиции из auth_item.
>   Т.е. пользователю (по user ID) можем назначить роль/разрешение (по
>   названиям).
>
> auth_rule - здесь хранятся имена классов правил, которые хранятся в
>   php файлах.
>
> Сейчас эти таблицы пустые.

НО у меня создается таблица "migration",но в ней 2 столбца
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: причем тут таблица `migrations` и  то, что команда migrate создает 4 таблицы?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну так написано "В консоли выполняем:
php yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations

Это создаст 4 таблицы в БД:" или я что то не так понял?

Comment: ну ок, а причем тут  `НО у меня создается таблица "migration",но в ней 2 столбца` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я имею в виду,что только она создается.
А какие поля в этих оставшихся 4-х таблицах,я не знаю.
Поэтому я и попросил тут помощи.

Comment: Попробуй эту статью почитать про RBAC
https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-prostaya-realizaciya-rbac-s-dvumya-rolyami.html